# Help: Timeline has turned red - how can I get back to default?

Tags: timeline

I am a completely beginner in Blender, and inadvertently have turned the timeline to 'red'.  I googled it, and for the life of me can't figure out what happened.  How do I just turn it back to normal?

[image: screenshot of the red bar on the timeline]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header color can be changed in
*Preferences > Themes > DopeSheet > ThemeSpace > Header*

[image]

Comment: ... or select theme preset - Blender Dark

Comment: Eh... That's actually both faster and easier to remember :). Damn.

Comment: I think the solve was as easy pressing the shortcut key for autotoggle - in my case, I had the BSMAX addon turned on and pressing 'n' made the bar go red vs. not...  Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: @ChrisL Glad you found a solution. Please post your comment as a full answer, so others can learn from it :). Thank you.